# how to remove \n from visualforce page when using escape="false" on apex:outputText

Tags: apex, html, visuaforce

I need to break the paragraph at the end of the line and add it in next line.
So i used substituting new line(\n) with break tag(
).

Here is the tag that i'm using on vf page.

```
 <td>
   <apex:outputText value="{!SUBSTITUTE(JSENCODE(quote.Description),'\n','<br/>')}" style="white-space:pre;" escape="false" />
</td>
```

it works fine but now i have an extra "\r" on each line. is there anyway i can get rid of this '\r' tag?
 [image]

Comment: Is there a reason as to why you cannot use `apex:outputField` instead of using `apex:outputText` ?

Comment: <apex:outputField doesnt allow attribute escape="false". that is why using outputText.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's actually a variety of line breaks used in the world, the common types today being LF (`\n`) and CRLF (`\r\n`). The reason for this is historical, but it's important to know that if you're using Windows, you're in the CRLF group, and if you're using Linux, you're in the LF group, and some other platforms might even be using just CR (but I don't know of any modern OSes that do this).

To fix the problem, you would need to take an extra step to remove the `\r` characters as well. However, I would say that all of this simply isn't necessary. Simply use the CSS `white-space: pre-line` and don't substitute line breaks; they should not be necessary. Also, using `escape="false"` is inherently risky, so I would advise against this.

---

Here's an example of preserving line spaces in the output:

## Sample Controller

```
public class q225036 {
    public String getOutput() {
        return 'Hello,\r\nWorld!\r\n\r\n\r\nGoodbye,\r\nWorld!';
    }
}
```

---

## Sample Page

```
<apex:page controller="q225036">
    <apex:outputText style="white-space: pre-line" value="{!output}" />
</apex:page>
```

---

The output:

```
Hello,
World!


Goodbye,
World!
```

You don't need to use `SUBSTITUTE`, and you don't need to use `JSENCODE`. This also prevents people from injecting malicious scripts and so on in to your page (which, by the way, `JSENCODE` wouldn't protect you from, you'd need to use `HTMLENCODE` instead). This technique also works even if you don't use a controller (I'm using one just to keep it self-contained).